# Vim: how to get the mode I'm currently in

Tags: vim

I'm writing a plugin for commenting the code in special way and it should act a bit different when called in visual or normal modes.

Is there a function or some way to determine the mode in which the user is (was) when the function was called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's

> mode([expr])    Return a string that indicates the current mode.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#mode%28%29

but that might not work since you're probably going to start command mode in the rhs of the mapping.

A more robust way would be to set up slightly different mappings like

```
nmap <Leader>c :call MyFunc('n')<CR>
vmap <Leader>c :call MyFunc('v')<CR>
```

and use the argument value to know what mode the user was in.

Comment: You should use `nnoremap`/`vnoremap` here, they are more stable (i.e. there are much less ways for the end-user to accidently break the mapping) and thus are the only option for a plugin.